# Interactive choropleth map with R Shiny and leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to create a shiny app where I can select the value that I want to plot into my map. It might be that this is a very easy task but I am new in Shiny and I can't figure it out.

I don't understand whether I have to use selectInput or if leaflet has a different way to interact with Shiny.

This is my code

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgdal)
library(shiny)


pal <- colorQuantile("YlGn", NULL, n = 5)

state_popup <- paste0("<strong>State: </strong>", 
                      africa$COUNTRY, 
                      "<br><strong>Resource Revenue(IMF)</strong>", 
                      africa$Africa_r_1)

leaflet_africa <- leaflet(data = africa) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(Africa_r_1), 
              fillOpacity = 0.8, 
              color = "#BDBDC3", 
              weight = 1, 
              popup = state_popup)



ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map1")
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet_africa
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is `africa` a publicly available dataset? Or can you `dput` part of it and add it to your question?